# Force File Download From Remote Server Downloads a Corrupted ZIP - PHP

Tags: php, download, http-headers, force-download

I am working on making a very simple password protected "file downloader" that force downloads from a remote server (mediafire) after entering a password it *seems* to work but the file is always corrupted, anytime I try to open it, windows says: "Windows cannot open the folder the compressed(zipped) folder 'C:/users..' is invalid". 
Here is the code for the download script:

```
$yourfile ='http://www.mediafire.com/file/filelinkhere';

 ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password']; // required


        if ($password <> "somepasswordhere") {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('//error: incorrect password//')</script>"; 
             header( "Refresh:0; url=https://www.home/transfer.php", true, 303);


        } else {

                        $filename = basename($yourfile);
                        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

                        $size = filesize($yourfile);
                        header('Content-Length: '.$size.'');
                        readfile($yourfile);
                        exit;       
        }
    }
```

Using advice from another related stack question I made sure that content-length header uses a real string, because filesize returns an integer. Does anyone know why the download is still coming through as corrupt?

Comment: Are you sure that `$size` holds the real file size of `$yourfile`? If not, try removing the line with `header(Content-Length)`. Also, can you please open the downloaded file with a hex editor (or Notepad++) and check if it really contains a ZIP file? The first two bytes should be "PK".

Comment: After your suggestion I opened up the corrupt zip in a text editor and it seems to be downloading a webpage? I realized now that it is downloading the mediafire webpage that holds the download button, not the actual link of the download.  Now if understand correctly however if i rightclick saveas on the download button on that page and use it it should work, but that link stops working after every download.. Any ideas? Am I better off hosting the file myself? It will be downloaded up to 50 times a day..

Comment: Either host the file yourself, or link people to the mediafire page. You're only making more trouble for yourself by trying to pipe the file through this script.

Comment: This kind of sites make a living from advertisement, so they usually have quite advanced anti-leeching systems in place. I am not sure, but I think that Dropbox has an API, so you could try using it.